# offset is always 0 in MongoDB rest service

Tags: mongodb, rest, offset

i want to scroll through all the pages of mongodb REST response.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc$ curl http://localhost:28017/bb/feeds/?limit=1
```

with no **offset** i get correct result

```
  {
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57254bd21d41c82413afed60" }, "variety" : "Other", "modal_price" : "2150", "commodity" : "Rice", "max_price" : "2200", "state" : "West Bengal", "min_price" : "2100", "district" : "Uttar Dinajpur", "timestamp" : "1462026632", "market" : "Islampur", "id" : "87200341", "arrival_date" : "30/04/2016" }
  ],

  "total_rows" : 1 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

But when i pass **offset=2** i still get the same result

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc$ curl http://localhost:28017/bb/feeds/?limit=1&offset=2

{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57254bd21d41c82413afed60" }, "variety" : "Other", "modal_price" : "2150", "commodity" : "Rice", "max_price" : "2200", "state" : "West Bengal", "min_price" : "2100", "district" : "Uttar Dinajpur", "timestamp" : "1462026632", "market" : "Islampur", "id" : "87200341", "arrival_date" : "30/04/2016" }
  ],

  "total_rows" : 1 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The URL parameter you need to pass is actually `skip`, not `offset`:

```
curl http://localhost:28017/bb/feeds/?limit=1&skip=2
```

... which somewhat confusingly is indicated in the JSON output as the `offset` value.

Note: the built-in REST interface in MongoDB is extremely limited in terms of features and security, and deprecated as at MongoDB 3.2. I would strongly recommend looking into an alternative (and actively maintained) REST API. For a starting point see [HTTP Interfaces](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) in the MongoDB manual.